# Toast hide behind the keyboard on BB10

Tags: android, cascade, blackberry-10

I ported the android application to BB10. In application if keyboard is open at the same time if toast is display it is hide behind the keyboard on BB10 and user not able to see the toast message. In Android application it works fine only issue face is in BB10.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

set Toast Gravity Top

```
Toast t = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "TOP | RIGHT", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        t.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.RIGHT, 0, 0); 
        t.show();
```

Comment: how to do it in a Blackberry 10 app using qt C++